# Cakephp call .php file inside folder

Tags: php, cakephp

i have a separate folder called socio which contains all core php files and index.php. i want to use this in cakephp under some div . Please help me how to proceed with this . where should i put socio folder in cake php . And how to call index.php which is located inside socio folder.
I want to add this socio folder in cakephp div

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your folder inside your project's webroot folder. You can call it using

```
<your-website-url>/socio/
```

Comment: i want to load socio/index.php inside a div of cakephp view file. can u suggest how to do

Comment: why do you want to load index.php content inside a div? If it is a single file you can  call it using ajax in cakephp

Answer (score 0):

Keep that socio folder under webroot directory. you can call the files inside that directory directly.